# Twig - how to merge two-dimensional hashes so that sub-hash is not overriden

Tags: twig

I've encountered this problem. I wanted to merge these two hashes:

```
    {% set additional_context = {
        attributes:{
            'class': 'post-link',
            'data-confirm-text': params.confirm
        }
    } %}

    {% set ajax_context = {
        attributes: {
            'class': '',
            'data-href': target,
        }
    } %}
```

Doing this:

`{% additional_context = additional_context|merge(ajax_context) %}`

would override `additiona_context.attributes` with `ajax_context.attributes`.

I'd like to have `attributes` hashes merged as well, not overriden. **I cannot change the name of the sub-hash** - it has to be `attributes`.

I didn't find a neat way to do it. Ideas much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can write twig extension with function for this

Comment: @MaxP. this is a good idea :)